# CAKeyframeAnimation - Stopping Infinite Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cakeyframeanimation

I have the following lines of code to run animation with some frames.

```
- (void)setAnimation {
    /* creating a layer */
    CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    [layer setBounds:self.bounds];
    [layer setPosition:NSMakePoint(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds),CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))];
    [self.layer addSublayer:layer];

    /* creating frames */
    NSArray *array = [appDelegate getAnimationFrames]; // Extracting an array containing NSImage objects from appDelegate

    /* setting up animation */
    keyFrameAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation]; // A CAKeyframeAnimation object declared in the header file
    [keyFrameAnimation setKeyPath:@"contents"];
    [keyFrameAnimation setValues:array];
    [keyFrameAnimation setCalculationMode:@"discrete"];
    [keyFrameAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [keyFrameAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    keyFrameAnimation.duration = 1.0;
    [layer addAnimation:keyFrameAnimation forKey:nil];
}
```

This is my first time using **CAKeyframeAnimation**.  And it works fine for now.  The only question I have is how to break the loop if the repeat count is set to **HUGE_VALF**.  The API documentation doesn't appear helpful in this regard since it will return nothing if I search for 'setRepeatCount.'  Meanwhile, the code is for a Cocoa application, but I'll open this topic for iOS as well since there is little departure between OS X and iOS as far as this topic is concerned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the animation is added to the layer the layer creates a copy, so further changes to the animation object don't do anything.

You can use `[layer removeAllAnimations]` to stop the animation.

Comment: Hmm...  That's what I thought.  I'll test it now.

Comment: Yes.  That does it.  I'll be back in 30 seconds to click on the accept button.  Thanks.